# Incompatibility between memoir and appendix package option titletoc

Tags: memoir, appendices, incompatibility

I'm trying to get "Appendix A" instead of just "A" for my appendix in the table of contents, and one solution to this seems to be `\usepackage[titletox]{appendix}`. However, it doesn't work with `memoir`. The following code gives the error "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package appendix":

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}
```

How can I solve it?

It works if I remove the `[titletoc]` argument or change document class to `article`.

Comment: Appendix is already included in `memoir` so you cannot use it with the class. I don't quite understand what that option should do.

Comment: @daleif It changes "A" in the TOC to "Appendix A".

Comment: In memoir that is just `\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname}`

Comment: @daleif Thanks. It seems to give "AppendixA" instead, though.

Comment: Sorry, `\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}`, see the `memoir` manual

Comment: Thanks! I tried appending a space before, and that didn't work (I understand why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just add it as an answer.

The `memoir` way is to add

```
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
```

to the preamble.