# Option clash from another class emulating package

Tags: memoir, appendices, option-clash

I am using ShareLaTex with the [UC Berkeley Thesis template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/university-of-california-berkeley-thesis).

I want to load `appendix` with the `titletoc` and `header` options:

```
\usepackage[titletoc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

It throws a compile error.

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package appendix.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \usepackage
                {algorithmic}
The package appendix has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [titletoc,toc]
```

I gather `appendix` is being loaded from the `memoire` class used by the `ucbthesis` class included with the template. Digging into the raw logs I find this:

```
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
```

**So... is there a way I can tell `memoir` to not emulate `appendix`?**

Here is a sample from the `ucbthesis` class where `memoire` is passed a bunch of options.

```
\newcommand\thes@sidedness{-1}
\DeclareOption{oneside}
  {\renewcommand\thes@sidedness{1}\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}
  {\renewcommand\thes@sidedness{2}\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

%  Changing the default point size from 10pt to 12pt uses a similar procedure,
%  but it's messier.

\newcommand\thes@ptsize{0}
\DeclareOption{9pt}
  {\renewcommand\thes@ptsize{9}\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
%yada yada yada
\DeclareOption{*pt}
  {\renewcommand\thes@ptsize{99}\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

% Other options are passed on to the memoir class.

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
```

Comment: [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) does provide `\DisemulatePackage{appendix}`, but that only ensures that you can load the package. It does not, however, take care of commands that are already defined. Perhaps, instead of following this route, you could explain what [`appendix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) provides that `memoir` does not, as it may be easier to update `memoir` to do what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, you can use

```
\DisemulatePackage{appendix}
```

to stop `memoir` claiming that `appendix` is loaded, but then if you try to load it

```
\documentclass[titletoc,header]{memoir}
\DisemulatePackage{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

you get multiple errors starting

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@@ppsavesec already defined.
```

the appendix functionality isn't implemented by loading `appendix` with some fixed options, it is just embedded in the core `memoir` code as far as I can see in the sources. You should look to see if there is a "memoir-way" for whatever layout you wanted.

Comment: Yes, solution is to not fight memoir. \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
to rename (not one my original goals in this post, but hey)
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116523/incompatibility-between-memoir-and-appendix-package-option-titletoc

Comment: And use the `\addappheadtotoc` command from `memoir` as documented on p.78
http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf

Comment: Found this on a fast google hit, and still the best way to get memoir to chill in 2020.